# Filtering a datagridview that is bound to a dataset with a textbox c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to filter a datagridview that has been bound to a dataset. The thing is, when I type data into my textbox, the app stops and the error is that the column I'm trying to filter doesn't exist. I tried populating the datagridview with a string query and filtering works properly, but I can't update the datagridview (I don't know why). That's why I'm populating it with a dataset instead of the query. Any suggestions? This is what I have:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Items");
private void LoadDataGrid()
{
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Items.ItemID AS #, Items.SerialNo AS 'SERIALNO', Items.Description AS DESCRIPTION, Items.MaxVoltage, Items.FrameSize, Items.ArrivalDate, Items.DepartureDate, Items.Notes, Items.MechType, Items.[Fix-Drawout], CONCAT(Location.Rack, Location.Row, Location.Columnn, Location.Position) AS LOCATION, ItemStatus.Description AS STATUS, Type.Description AS TYPE, Manufacturers.Description AS MANUFACTURERS FROM Items INNER JOIN Location ON Items.LocationID = Location.LocationID INNER JOIN ItemStatus ON Items.Status = ItemStatus.StatusID INNER JOIN Type ON Items.TypeID = Type.TypeID INNER JOIN Manufacturers ON Items.ManufacturerID = Manufacturers.ManufacturerID", AEAcnn))
{
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
}
```

This is the filter expression I'm using (with a combobox)

```
private void txtFilter_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if (cmbFilterSearch.Text == "TYPE")
{
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("TYPE LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox14.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
}
}
```

The app crashes when the column TYPE can't be found, even though the name is actually TYPE.

Comment: This question would be better if you included your code attempts for people to review.

Comment: My bad! There's what I have.

Comment: You haven't shown the filter expression you're using

Comment: Right! There it is.

Comment: Put brackets around type. `"[TYPE] LIKE '%{0}%'"`

Comment: It didn't work. :(

Comment: I'm not sure it matters but you have a table named TYPE but then you also define a column alias that is also TYPE.  I would suggest using a different column alias.

Comment: If your combobox is bound, look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817220/getting-selected-value-of-databound-combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string str = string.Format("[TYPE] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox14.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
            dt.CaseSensitive = false;
            DataTable dt1 = dt.Select(str).CopyToDataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        }
```

Comment: Well, the app doesn't crash with this but now it won't filter a thing.

Comment: But my search need to be filtered with a combobox, 

    (cmbFilterSearch.Text == "TYPE")

and you don't include it in your answer, I did and the app crashes again

Comment: Comboboxes are touchy at times. Depends on how they are filled. Try instead of `cmbFilterSearch.Text ==` replace `Text` with `SelectedItem` or `SelectedText` or `SelectedValue`. I've had a similar problem with comboboxes. Try all 3 and see which one works.

Comment: I tried all three and nothing worked. This project hates me. Lol

Answer (score 0):

Despite the unconventional column names, I don't see anything incorrect with the code if you are getting past filling the data table with the adapter, which apparently is the case since you get no error until the keypress event. Since we can't see the entire context of the code I suspect you are not binding the data you think you are, or the binding is changing somewhere else that you haven't noticed.
See [this LINQPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/9mtgtu.linq) for proof it works:

```
Form frm = new Form();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Items");
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
TextBox textBox14 = new TextBox();
TextBox cmbFilterSearch = new TextBox();

void Main()
{   
    PopulateDataTable(dt);  
    BuildForm(frm, dt);
    Application.Run(frm);
}

void BuildForm(Form frm, DataTable dt)
{
    frm.Height = 500;
    frm.Width = 900;

    cmbFilterSearch.Text = "TYPE";
    frm.Controls.Add(cmbFilterSearch);

    textBox14.Text = "filter...";
    textBox14.Location = new Point(0,50);
    frm.Controls.Add(textBox14);
    textBox14.KeyPress += txtFilter_KeyPress;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Location = new Point(0, 80);
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.Width = 800;  
    frm.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
}

void txtFilter_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbFilterSearch.Text == "TYPE")
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("TYPE LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox14.Text);
        Console.WriteLine(dv.RowFilter);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
    }
}

void PopulateDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("#", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("'SERIALNO'", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MaxVoltage", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("FrameSize", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ArrivalDate", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("DepartureDate", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Notes", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MechType", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Fix-Drawout", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LOCATION", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("STATUS", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TYPE", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MANUFACTURERS", typeof(string));

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = 1;
    row[1] = "9083290823";
    row[2] = "Mares eat oats";
    row[3] = "12v";
    row[4] = "60";
    row[5] = DateTime.Now;
    row[6] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
    row[7] = "and does eat oats";
    row[8] = "and little lambs";
    row[9] = "eat ivy.";
    row[10] = "Cancelled";
    row[11] = "KEYWORD";
    row[12] = "ACME";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = 2;
    row[1] = "43537953";
    row[2] = "Mares eat oats";
    row[3] = "12v";
    row[4] = "60";
    row[5] = DateTime.Now;
    row[6] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
    row[7] = "and does eat oats";
    row[8] = "and little lambs";
    row[9] = "eat ivy.";
    row[10] = "Cancelled";
    row[11] = "Reserved Word";
    row[12] = "Conglomico";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = 3;
    row[1] = "9083290823";
    row[2] = "Mares eat oats";
    row[3] = "12v";
    row[4] = "60";
    row[5] = DateTime.Now;
    row[6] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
    row[7] = "and does eat oats";
    row[8] = "and little lambs";
    row[9] = "eat ivy.";
    row[10] = "Cancelled";
    row[11] = "Identifier";
    row[12] = "Enormico";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection ;
            SqlCommand command ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataView dv ;
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            sql = "Select * from product";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Filter DataView");
                adapter.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();

                dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0], "Product_Price < = 3000", "Product_Name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```